# Why is this simple UI-Router example not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I feel guilty about asking such a question...Still, here goes
I have a fairly basic UI-Router example, however for the life of me I am not able to get it to work.

The body looks like this:

```
 <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <a ui-sref="home" class="navbar-brand">My Product</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The app. js module looks like this

```
(function(){
    //Module Declaration
  var app = angular.module("movieViewer", ["ui.router"]);


    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "main.html",
      //    controller: "MainCtrl",
        })
    }
  ]);

}());
```

Fairly simple, however it doesnt work. Will appreciate any heads up on this.

[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FdCAxHB4phMADQ0lwcDJ)

Comment: "it doesn't work" what does that mean? do you see any console errors? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to kick off angular on page by adding `ng-app` directive with module name `movieViewer` on `html` tag.

```
ng-app="movieViewer"
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAE9CUAHpmBkELfEYXnH?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, that was a great explanation as well.

Comment: @w2olves glad to know that helped, Thanks :)